# How to put space between horizontal input fields in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a basic react project. I want to put space between 2 horizontal input fields ( without grid ). Anyhelp will be helpful as I am in learning phase.

The style I am using for fields

```
.grocery {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: var(--clr-grey-10);
  border-top-left-radius: var(--radius);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--radius);
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
}
```

The react code snippet:

```
 <div className='form-control'>
        <input type='text' name='Principal'className='grocery' placeholder='principal amount' value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>
          {isEditing ? 'edit' :'submit'}
        </button>
        <input type='text' name='cash inflow'className='grocery' placeholder='cash inflow' value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>
          {isEditing ? 'edit' :'submit'}
        </button>
      </div>
```

[image: The two input fields between where I want to put space]

Comment: Add margin to `.grocery` to create that extra space you want

Comment: Thank you, I added ``` margin-left: 25px;``` in ```.grocery``` and its perfectly reflecting.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `margin-right` to  `.submit-btn`. This will make sure, the button and input will stay together.
(Also, you can use `:first-child` for `.submit-btn` so that margin is only applied to the 1st button and not all.)

```css
.grocery {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: #F1F5F8;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  color: #F1F5E4;
}

.submit-btn{
  margin-right: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<div className='form-control'>
        <input type='text' name='Principal' class='grocery' placeholder='principal amount'>
        <button type='submit' class='submit-btn'>
          submit
        </button>
        <input type='text' name='cash inflow' class='grocery' placeholder='cash inflow'>
        <button type='submit' class='submit-btn'>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: This also works for me, either need to add ```margin-right``` in ```.submit-btn``` or ```margin-left:25px``` in ```.grocery```

Comment: @Priya Yeah. But it will also get applied to 1st input, which will also cause it to move 25px from left.

Comment: right. Chances are there 1st field moves more towards left(if I use more left margin px) which cause unequal margins for both input boxes, to balance I used both ```margin-right:25px``` in ```.submit-btn``` and ```margin-left:25px``` in ```.grocery```, this is balancing and equalizes both input box margins.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

> `&nbsp;`

between both elements in the HTML to get the space quickly. However, a better approach would be to add margin-right as explained by @TechySharnav.

Comment: `& nbsp;` needs to be `&nbsp;` (without space), if used. CSS styling might make more sense, in case of several input fields.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: @AizazMalik I asked space between horizontal input fields, it think what you shared is applicable for input fields in next line(vertically placed)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your elements in container elements to do this and keep the button and input together.

```css
.form-control {
  background-color: teal;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
}

.grocery {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-control'>
  <div class="container">
     <input type='text' name='Principal' class='grocery' placeholder='principal amount' />
     <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type='text' name='cash inflow' class='grocery' placeholder='cash inflow'/>
    <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I added 2 container divs with a padding of 1em and set display-property of the `.form-control` div to flex.

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-control {
  background-color: teal;
  display: flex;
  **justify-content: space-between;**
}

.grocery {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-control'>
  <div class="container">
     <input type='text' name='Principal' class='grocery' placeholder='principal amount' />
     <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type='text' name='cash inflow' class='grocery' placeholder='cash inflow'/>
    <button type='submit' className ='submit-btn'>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```